# Javascript - document.write prevents other content

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code

```
<body>
<script>document.write("<div>hello world </div>");</script>
<h1>hello></h1>
</body>
```

However, the h1 tag does not show...

Comment: It should work, unless whichever browser you're using doesn't like that you missed the closing `</h1>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, Close your `</h1>`

```html
<body>
<script>document.write("<div>hello world </div>");</script>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  tag is not closed, closed that and check I have checked it IE,Mozilla and chrome, please have look attached screen shot it's showing me.
can you please send me your screen shot so that I can identify what issue are you facing.
 [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFcJ9.png)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<body>
<script>document.write("<div>hello world </div>");</script>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not close the h1 tag , you are finding difficult to get the expected output. Refer the following code :

```
<body>
<script>document.write("<div>hello world </div>");</script>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because that's how `document.write` works. You may want to use `innerHTML` instead.

[innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

**edit**

It's may work, but I think that is better to use `innerHTML`. (based on self experience, and other posts)